# Inline query for listing all pages from a namespace without any subobjects

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I need an inline query that lists all pages from a specific namespace, but without listing [subobjects](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Adding_subobjects) specified on these pages.

[Restricting results to a namespace](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Selecting_pages#Restricting_results_to_a_namespace) is possible like that:

```
{{#ask: [[ExampleNamespace:+]] }}
```

But it lists all subobjects, too.

Workarounds:

- Specify a category on these pages (subobjects don’t inherit it) and query for the category instead:

  ```
  {{#ask: [[ExampleCategory]] }}
  ```
- Specify a property on these pages (and never on the subobjects) and query for the property (with a [wildcard](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Selecting_pages#Wildcards) value) instead:

  ```
  {{#ask: [[ExampleProperty::+]] }}
  ```

But both workarounds require editing, which I would like to avoid. **Is there a better way to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a better way, but it looks like array formats/arrays and their `#arraymap` and `#arrayunique` functions are a way to go in order to trim SMW subobject tags and make the DISTINCT operation. Unfortunately, the solution below has **a query result limit issue** described as well (at least out of what I understand in SMW). In general, it may look like the following, and I will appreciate if someone suggests a nicer solution:

```xml
<!-- Fetch all pages from the "Live event" namespace -->
{{#arraydefine: QUERY_RESULT
| {{#ask: [[Live event:+]]
  | format = array
  | link = none <!-- NOTE: array item link -->
  | limit = 10000 <!-- NOTE: limit -->
  }}
}}

<!-- Store the mapped result into another array -->
{{#arraydefine: MAPPED_QUERY_RESULT
| {{#arraymap: {{#arrayprint: QUERY_RESULT}}
  | ,
  | $O <!-- NOTE: array map iterator value -->
  | {{#explode: $O <!-- NOTE: explode by hash -->
    | #
    | 0
    }}
  }}
| ,
| unique
}}

<!-- Generate links markup -->
{{#arraymap: {{#arrayprint: MAPPED_QUERY_RESULT}}
| ,
| $O
| [[$O]] <!-- NOTE: plain links -->
}}
```

The notes from the code above:

- **NOTE: array item link** - Not suppressing the links causes the mapper to be more complicated (including parsing HTML `<span>` tags and `class` attributes).
- **NOTE: limit** - This is probably the biggest issue here as the number of subobjects **affects** the query result. SMW by default limits the query results, and the maximum query limit cannot be overridden as far as I know. Having more rows, which count is greater than the limits is, will cause the 'Further limits' link to appear. Actually speaking, I have no idea how to work around it nicely.
- **NOTE: array map iterator value** - `{{#arraymap}}` seems to replace strings in the simplest way like `sed` or a simple text editor app do. So `$O` is used as the iterator value placeholder for the `formula` parameter trying not to clash with other string tokens.
- **NOTE: explode by hash** - `#ask` subobject results generate hashed links like `PageA#_159c1f213de2fcaf165f2c9c5c56686b`. Just getting rid of them. In case you need to strip wiki links, you might also play around with `[[` or `|` (encoded like `[<nowiki/>[` and `<nowiki>|</nowiki>` respectively)
- **NOTE: plain links** - The generated links will have underscores instead of spaces. Unfortunately, `[[{{#replace: $O | _ | <nowiki> </nowiki>}}]]` didn't work for me -- the underscores are simply consumed for some reason, however this approach is also recommended at the `#replace` function wiki page.

Some links:

- [SMW array result format](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Array_format)
- [SMW configuration](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Configuration)
- [SMW further results](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries#Result_limits_and_links_to_further_results)
- [#arraymap:](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Semantic_Forms_and_templates#arraymap)
- [#explode:](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions#.23explode:)
- [#replace:](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions#.23replace:)
- [Help:List the set of unique values for a property](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:List_the_set_of_unique_values_for_a_property) (pay attention at the "Limitations and issues" section)